# determine the limsup and the liminf as $x \to 0$ of this function?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

For $f(x)=\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as $x\to 0 $.

limsup should be $0$ and liminf should be $1$. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Since $|\sin (1/x) |\le 1$ you have $$|f(x)| \le | \sin x| \to 0$$

Answer (score 3):

No.

$|f(x)| \le | \sin x|$ for all $x$. Hence $f(x) \to 0$ for $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have here an example of the

**Claim**: if $\;\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)=0\;$ and $\;h(x)\;$ is a function defined in some neighborhood of $\;x_0\;$ *and bounded there* , then $\;\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)h(x)=0\;$

Thus, the limit of your function is zero, and then the lim sup and the lim inf. equal zero, too.

Comment: Hints to prove this claim?

Comment: @supremum Oh, it's very simple: suppose $\;|h(x)|<M\;$ in the said nieghborhood, and take *any* $\;\epsilon>0\;$ . Then, there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t. $$|x|<\delta\implies |g(x)|<\frac\epsilon M$$ so for this same $\;|x|<\delta\;$ we get$$|g(x)h(x)|=|g(x)||h(x)|<\frac\epsilon M\cdot M$$ and we're done...

Comment: You mean $|x-x_0|<\delta$?

Comment: @supremum Yes, of course. I just got distracted by your limit, but it is similar